# Remove new line only if after a number

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

I've collected some CSV data from terminal but every line is only 80 characters long so it's not importing properly.

Here's two lines of data:

```
28,26166,25180,23645,22824,21257,20080,18921,17893,16702,15650,14647,13667,12691
,11971,11179,10393,9885,9294,8930,8390,8079,7660,7341,6907,6425,6120,5789,5588,5
267,4924,4581,4246,4025,3857,

3423,3567,3636,3633,3714,3844,4543,5887,7287,8499,9
746,10704,11658,12591,13379,13950,14679,14954,14756,14224,13921,13494,12849,1230
0,11970,12240,12867,13475,14310,15962,17624,19105,21075,
```

I wanna remove the newline char **only** if it's after any number or comma, but not if it's only on it's own, since that means it's a new line of CSV data.

I couldn't figure out how to do this on shell with `sed`. If any other program like `awk` or `perl` is better for this scenario then feel free to show me a solution for that.

Expected output:

```
28,26166,25180,23645,22824,21257,20080,18921,17893,16702,15650,14647,13667,12691,11971,11179,10393,9885,9294,8930,8390,8079,7660,7341,6907,6425,6120,5789,5588,5267,4924,4581,4246,4025,3857,

3423,3567,3636,3633,3714,3844,4543,5887,7287,8499,9746,10704,11658,12591,13379,13950,14679,14954,14756,14224,13921,13494,12849,12300,11970,12240,12867,13475,14310,15962,17624,19105,21075,
```

Comment: Do you REALLY have a blank line between each input line and want that duplicated in your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the newline if it's preceded by a digit or comma:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if /[\d,]$/' input-file > output-file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the result
- `chomp` removes newline if present at the end
- `\d` matches a digit
- `$` matches the end of line

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` by reading in paragraph mode and replacing all `\n`

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub("\n","")} 1' ip.txt 
28,26166,25180,23645,22824,21257,20080,18921,17893,16702,15650,14647,13667,12691,11971,11179,10393,9885,9294,8930,8390,8079,7660,7341,6907,6425,6120,5789,5588,5267,4924,4581,4246,4025,3857,
3423,3567,3636,3633,3714,3844,4543,5887,7287,8499,9746,10704,11658,12591,13379,13950,14679,14954,14756,14224,13921,13494,12849,12300,11970,12240,12867,13475,14310,15962,17624,19105,21075,
```

To leave the blanks, set `ORS` to double newlines, however this will add an extra newline at end

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{gsub("\n","")} 1' ip.txt 
28,26166,25180,23645,22824,21257,20080,18921,17893,16702,15650,14647,13667,12691,11971,11179,10393,9885,9294,8930,8390,8079,7660,7341,6907,6425,6120,5789,5588,5267,4924,4581,4246,4025,3857,

3423,3567,3636,3633,3714,3844,4543,5887,7287,8499,9746,10704,11658,12591,13379,13950,14679,14954,14756,14224,13921,13494,12849,12300,11970,12240,12867,13475,14310,15962,17624,19105,21075,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)
```

and replace with empty string.

Comment: That will not work with any standard UNIX tool. When posting any solution, throwing out a standalone regexp is useless since all tools support different regexp flavors, some with different options to enable different flavors. Always show a regexp in the context of the tool that will support that regexp or it's just so much noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 's/([\d,])\n([\d,])/$1$2/sg' (file)
```

should do it.

That is, read the file without line delimiters, treat the whole thing as one string and remove the newlines that are preceded and followed by a digit or comma.

Comment: Sorry, I had removed the digit and comma as well.